# Tracking a user using userID in Flurry Analytics

Tags: flurry, userid, user-tracking, flurry-analytics

I have a simple question,
Is it possible to track a user using their userID in Flurry?
I know I can user setUserID in my event but is it possible to see all the events from a user say abc@xyz.com has gone through?
Currently, I can see it as Following For User 036(is there a way to find the same using userID):[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to filter on a single user ID in User Journeys